# CSS Selector for hide/display based on hover of a:link

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm having a little trouble figuring out which selector or selector hierarchy I should use with my CSS to get a 'sub menu' to display.

I want to have the sub-menu appear based on the hovering of `a:link` within a completely separate `<nav>` within a `<ul>`.

I'm just not sure how to write the CSS in order to obtain that effect

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <nav id="nav" class="nav-holder">
        <ul id="nav" class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Links!</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links!</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links!</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links!</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links!</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links!</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="cleared"></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="submenunav"></div>
    </div>
```

The wrong CSS

```
.submenunav { display:none;}

#nav ul#nav li a:hover .submenunav {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:500;
   display:block;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
   width:940px;
   height:200px;
   background:#E9EAEE;
   border-bottom:9px #67B7E1 solid;
   box-shadow:0 8px 6px -6px black;
}​
```

My fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/NVwks/

The desired effect would be for the submenu block to appear based on hovering over any links, although eventually I will be giving the `a:links` unique classes for unique submenus.

Many thanks SO.

Comment: It looks to be that this is not possible to do with CSS alone. The `.submenunav` element is not a child or sibling of the links and you cannot "go back up" with CSS selectors.

Comment: In `<li><a href="#">Links!<div class="submenunav"></div></a></li>` you can do the trick in CSS with `li>a:hover .submenunav { display: block; }`. But in your example, i don't think you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your `a:link` elements are contained within your `nav` element, which as you say is completely separate from the sub-menu elements you want to display. This separation in your structure makes it impossible to achieve with `:hover` and other CSS selectors alone.

There doesn't seem to be much room for restructuring your markup, so you may have to use a script to achieve your desired functionality.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was hoping that wasn't the case, but now I suppose I'll resort to JQuery to accomplish this.  Thank you for your support!